# How can you set text positon within an input element of type password?

Tags: html, css, user-interface, web

I have an `input type="password"` object that I need to display an over-sized password font.

I'm having trouble getting the password dots to center and space correctly.  I have a simplified version in a jsfiddle posted below.

`padding-bottom` does not work, because in my case it just removes part of the dot and doesn't move it up.  I also tried `line-height` to no avail.

What I'm referring to is the position of the password dots being to low in the input element when I make the size larger.  If I pad the bottom it removes part of the dots, but I just need to move them slightly up.

Also in response to other answers, setting the height of the input size to the font size will not work because that makes the input much too large.  I need to make the password dots much larger than their initial size but without making the input larger.  When I change the size it pushes the dots down, and I need to bring them back to center in the smaller box, but without using `padding-bottom`.

```
.myPasswordStyle
{
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 50px;
}
<input type="password" class="myPasswordStyle">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nfcrbd7m/

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're asking here. If you had to sum up your **question** in one sentence, what would it be?

Comment: Do you really need to specify a specific height for the password box? If you let it size according to the font, all is well: https://jsfiddle.net/sunz3n7a/1/

Comment: @ArtOfCode edited question to be more clear.

Comment: Styling & position of the 'dots' is browser specific so I'm doubtful if you will find any single property that will have any cross browser compatibility.

Comment: @Paulie_D That's a good point.  Do you changing the 'dots' to a different character would be a better solution?

Comment: @CodeKiller Doubtful...even if you could change the "dots"...you'd still suffer from the same problem I suspect.

Answer (score 2):

You could just remove the height property and let the font size set the height of the input:

```
.myPasswordStyle {
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

Adding a little bottom padding will make it look more vertically aligned when it's a password field, i.e.

```
.myPasswordStyle {
    font-size: 50px;        
    padding-bottom:5px;
}
```

Comment: The problem with that is the input field will get too large.  I wanted to make the font larger in the smaller box.  But when you make the font larger in the small box, it tries to center it in what would be the potential height.  But now I need to center it in the smaller element.